# PrimeFaces calendar change pattern after date selection

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I use [PrimeFaces calendar component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml) on page. Pattern attribute is set to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. Component value attribute is linked to `java.util.Date` variable in bean. When i open the page date in format which i expect, but after change of the value, format will always change into different format.

Expected format - `06/15/2015 08:00:30`

Format after change of value - `06/15/2015 8:00 AM`

Component ussage.

```
<p:calendar value="#{someBean.someJava.UtilDateVariable}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" locale="en">
     <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
</p:calendar>
```

I already tried to check primefaces showcase and documentation, different locale specification and also usage of the localization script for current localization but with no effect.

Every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>`. This tag converts String to Object and viceversa.

The Primefaces documentation only uses the Pattern attribute and sometimes the locale attribute causes troubles.
Try:

```
<p:calendar value="#{someBean.someJava.UtilDateVariable}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Miguel . I tried it also without converter and also with / without  locale but without success.

Comment: Miguels answer is straight from the show case. i also tested it and it worked. There must be something in your bean or your getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had simalar problem, calendar showing right date, but when I opened the datepicker the pattern seemed to be wrong.

After three hours I ended it was bootstrap pattern.

To solve quickly I included a javascript file on the jsf page with setting for pattern:

In XHTML

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="myscripts.js" />
```

IN JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
});
```